# Launch image of my iphone application inverted on iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, screen, launch, default.png

I'm working on an iPhone application (not an universal one).
When I launch this application on my iPad, the laucnh screen (DEfault.png) is not displayed correctly: it's inverted (as if the iPad was upsidedown, but it's not).

Any solution for that?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Alexandre

Comment: are you sure that the orientation lock is not set?

Comment: yes I'm.
the issue is also present on the simulator!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify different launch images for different orientations, by following [this tutorial](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/ipad/ipad-managing-multiple-launch-images.html) but if you only have one image, you most likely just need to flip your original image around.

Comment: Possible duplicate of, er, your other nearly identical answer ;)

Comment: SO double posted it for some reason. I've deleted the other.